# Hacer que un iframe con un vídeo de youtube no ralentice la pag web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un apartado en el cual tú pinchas sobre un `<a>` y se abre un `iframe` con el vídeo de Youtube. Tengo 30 `<a>` que hacen 30 iframes diferentes los cuales muestran vídeos diferentes, al ejecutar esta página tarda mucho en cargar, ¿cómo podría disminuir el tiempo de carga de la página?

Este sería el código:

```
<  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1"> 1. Gangnan Style | | <strong>PSY </strong>  </><br> 

  <div class="modal fade" id="1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Gangnan Style | | <strong>PSY </strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe width="99%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?controls=0"> </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando alguna biblioteca como Bootstrap? ¿Cuál es el código JS para abrir el modal y ver el vídeo?

Comment: Si estoy utilizando Bootstrap. El código que utilizo es el de arriba, las librerías utilizadas son:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías dejar los iframes sin asignar el atributo src y asignárselo en el momento de mostrar el vídeo en cuestión (cuando el usuario haga click para mostrarlo).
Esto aceleraría la carga inicial aunque tardaría más a la hora de mostrar un vídeo concreto.

Otra opción es asignar todas las urls de los vídeos una vez completada la carga del resto de la página. Algo así:

```js
$(function(){
  function cargaDeVideos(){
    $('#video1').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?controls=0');
  }
  
  setTimeout(cargaDeVideos);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Gangnan Style | | <strong>PSY </strong></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe width="99%" height="315" id="video1"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias un saludo :)

Comment: Va de lujo y he mejorado el tiempo de carga